# C# HTTPS Post. Web Server Throwing "Not Well formed" Exception

Tags: c#

Im attempting a Https post from a C# application. I could connect to the web server and authinticate the user. The server is configured to send through some data in responce to a POST query. If tried from a browser the server does repond properly. However, when I attempt the same query from my application, the server responds with an error saying

"Server exception: not well-formed"

Its an Apache webserver running on Cent OS.

Below is the code. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

---

Example of a POST link that server responds to correctly when tried from a browser:

https://some.server.com/some/local_dir/abc.cgi?command=ACommand&entitytype=AnEntity

---

My C# code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate
{ return true; };

NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("User", "Password");
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add("https://some.server.com", 443, "Basic", nc);

HttpWebRequest WebRequest =
(HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://some.server.com/some/local_dir/abc.cgi");

WebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
WebRequest.Method = "POST";
WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
WebRequest.Credentials = cc;
WebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
WebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; " +
        "Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; " +
        ".NET CLR 2.0.50215)";

byte[] AuthBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("User:Password");
string sAuth = Convert.ToBase64String(AuthBytes);
WebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + sAuth);


byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("command=ACommand&entitytype=AnEntity");
using (Stream requestStream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

try
{

    WebResponse response = WebRequest.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: "+ex.Message);
}
```

---

Server responce:

12790618993000Server exception: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 7

Comment: just curious - have you tried WebClient?  It will let you stop doing some of this manual work and might fix whatever the issue is.  Fiddler (or something else that can show you the actual traffic) would be great to use, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your format, but can I suggest doing the following:

1. Download and install Fiddler - http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
2. Download and install my Fiddler extension - Request to Code - http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code
3. Run Fiddler.
4. Configure Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS - Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS and tick the "Decrypt HTTPS Traffic" box.
5. Visit your properly responding URL: https://some.server.com/some/local_dir/abc.cgi?command=ACommand&entitytype=AnEntity
6. Drag that session row from the Fiddler session list into the 'Code' tab.
7. It will generate C# code that you can use to make the same request.

Let me know if it's still not working if you try that.

Comment: I just did that and found a problem with the post arguments. Fiddler is a great tool and thanks for direction me in the right direction. cheers.

Comment: Great to hear that!  If you're pleased with my response, can you accept it?